# How to perform sorting using pyreadstat library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using `pyreadstat` library to read sas dataset files(*.sas7bdat, *.xpt).

```
import pyreadstat as pd
import pandas as pda
import sys
import json
FILE_LOC = sys.argv[1]
PAGE_SIZE = 100
PAGE_NO = int(sys.argv[2])-1
START_FROM_ROW = (PAGE_NO * PAGE_SIZE)
pda.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
pda.set_option('display.width',None)
pda.set_option('display.max_rows',None)
df = pd.read_sas7bdat(FILE_LOC, row_offset=START_FROM_ROW, row_limit=PAGE_SIZE,output_format='dict')
finalList = []
for key in df[0]:
    l =  list(map(lambda x: str(x) if str(x)=="nan" else x, df[0][key].tolist()))
    nparray = {key:l}
    finalList.append(nparray)
return json.dumps(finalList)
```

How to perform sorting using `pyreadstat` library?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by sorting?

Comment: sorting on the entire data. In sas7bdat file I have 100 columns so I can sort the entire data on one of column

Comment: just use df.sort_values

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Pyreadstat cannot return sorted data. You need to read the sas7bdat file data into memory and then you can sort it.

In order to sort, take into consideration that Pyreadstat returns a tuple of a pandas dataframe and a metadata object. Once you have the dataframe you can sort it by one or multiple columns using the [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) method . Therefore it is better to get a dataframe rather than a dictionary in this case.

```
df, meta = pd.read_sas7bdat(FILE_LOC, row_offset=START_FROM_ROW, row_limit=PAGE_SIZE)
#sort
df_sorted = df.sort_values(["columnA", "columnB"])
#replace nans
df = df.fillna("nan")
# you can directly convert to json
#check the options in the documentation, it may give you something different as you want.
out = df.to_json()
# otherwise transform to dict and build your json as before
out = df.to_dict(orient='list')
```

Comment: But here we are applying sorting on result set or the result which we got from `read_sas7bdat` It's not sorting entire dataset

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Is it your question if the function read_sas7bdat can give you sorted data?

Comment: yeah if `read_sas7bdat` can give sorted data.

Comment: I see, no it cannot. It has to read all the data from the file to memory (a dataframe or a dict) and only then you will be able to sort. So my suggestion still holds.